Unknown LocationRestriction type in Places Autocomplete API Android
Trying to restrict results from AutoComplete predictions to a set radius. Here's my code:
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS);

    List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
    countryList.add(companyInfo.getCountry());

    CircularBounds bounds = CircularBounds.newInstance(new `LatLng(businessLocation.getLatitude(), businessLocation.getLongitude()), companyInfo.getRadius() * 1000);`

    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
            .setCountries(countryList)
            .setLocationRestriction(bounds)
            .setHint(context.getString(R.string.start_typing_an_address))
            .build(context);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

App keeps crashing saying
java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown LocationRestriction type

Google search didn't return any results that mentions this particular error.

It is a reported issue that hasn't been fixed as of today (4-4-24).
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317161101
I'll update this once google fixes the issue.
